# XSLT: Fill table based on common attribute value under different elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I've been trying to create a table with XSLT based on identical attribute values in XML file. I'm struggling with linking the elements based on identical attributes and looping through the XML file retrieving the necessary data.

The XML file i have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LandXML>
  <Survey>
    <GPSSetup id="Setup1" stationName="Ref1">
    </GPSSetup>
    <GPSSetup id="Setup2" stationName="Ref2">
    </GPSSetup>
    <GPSSetup id="Setup3" stationName="Ref3">
    </GPSSetup>
    ...
  </Survey>
  <Survey>
    <GPSSetup id="id1" name="0001">
    </GPSSetup>
    <GPSSetup id="id2" name="0002">
    </GPSSetup>
    <GPSSetup id="id3" name="0003">
    </GPSSetup>
    ...
    <GPSVector setupID_a="Ref1">
      <TargetPoint pntRef="0001"></TargetPoint>
    </GPSVector>
    <GPSVector setupID_a="Ref1">
      <TargetPoint pntRef="0002"></TargetPoint>
    </GPSVector>
    <GPSVector setupID_a="Ref2">
      <TargetPoint pntRef="0003"></TargetPoint>
    </GPSVector>
    ...
  </Survey>
  <HexagonLandXML>
    <Point uniqueID="0001">
      <Coordinates n="1234"></Coordinates>
    </Point>
    <Point uniqueID="name2">
      <Coordinates n="1225"></Coordinates>
    </Point>
    <Point uniqueID="name3">
      <Coordinates n="1335"></Coordinates>
    </Point>
  </HexagonLandXML>
</LandXML>
```

I want to output a html file where under every "stationName" value that is found in the XML, a table is created where the corresponding "pntRef" and "n" values are shown.

The output i would like to achieve:

```
Ref1:
0001   1234
0002   1225

Ref2:
0003   1335
```

The XSLT file i have made so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
            xmlns:l="http://www.landxml.org/schema/LandXML-1.2"
            xmlns:h="http://xml.hexagon.com/schema/HeXML-1.7"
            xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
            exclude-result-prefixes="h l"
            extension-element-prefixes="h l msxsl">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="no" encoding="utf-8"/> 
<xsl:variable name="fileExt" select="'html'"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <head>
      <style>
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//l:LandXML/l:Survey[1]/l:GPSSetup">
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:key name="keyLGPSVector" match="l:GPSVector" use="@setupID_A"/>
<xsl:key name="keyH" match="h:Point" use="@uniqueID"/>

<xsl:template match="//l:LandXML/l:Survey[1]/l:GPSSetup">
  <xsl:variable name="Survey1L" select="."/>
  <xsl:variable name="Survey1LID" select="key('keyLGPSVector', $Survey1L/@id)"/>
  <xsl:variable name="PointH" select="key('keyH', $Survey1L/@id)"/>

  <xsl:for-each select=".">
    <h5>
    <xsl:value-of select="@stationName"/>
    </h5>

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Number</th>
                <th>n [m]</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <xsl:for-each select="$Survey1LID">
                <xsl:if test="$Survey1LID/@setupID_A = $Survey1L/@id">
                <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="current()/l:TargetPoint/@pntRef"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="$PointH/h:Coordinates/@n"/></td>
                </tr>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</xsl:for-each>
```

With this i can achieve that the correct "pntRef" values are shown under each "Ref()" heading, but i cannot get the "n" value. From reading this forum i understand that for-each is probably not the best element to be used in this case.

Sorry if the editing is wrong or non-transparent, this is my first post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need; see comments for explanations:  [XSLT Fiddle](http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtpK)

#### Code:

```xslt
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math map array"
    version="3.0">

    <!-- create the html body -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <style></style>
            </head>
            <body>  
                 <xsl:apply-templates select="/LandXML/Survey/GPSSetup[./@stationName]" />
            </body>  
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- create an entry per station -->
    <xsl:template match="/LandXML/Survey/GPSSetup">
        <xsl:variable name="stationName" select="./@stationName" />
        <h5>
            <xsl:value-of select="$stationName"/>
        </h5>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Number</th>
                    <th>n [m]</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                 <xsl:apply-templates select="../../Survey/GPSVector[@setupID_a = $stationName]/TargetPoint" />
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- find all target points related to the station -->
    <xsl:template match="/LandXML/Survey/GPSVector/TargetPoint">
        <xsl:variable name="pntRef" select="./@pntRef" />
         <xsl:apply-templates select="../../../HexagonLandXML/Point[@uniqueID = $pntRef]/Coordinates" />
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- create a row for each target point / coordinate pair under the station -->
    <xsl:template match="/LandXML/HexagonLandXML/Point/Coordinates">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="../@uniqueID" /></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="./@n" /></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

#### Explanation

- The template `<xsl:template match="/LandXML/HexagonLandXML/Point/Coordinates">` creates the rows with the `uniqueID` and `n` values; but does not work out where these should be placed.
- The code `<xsl:apply-templates select="../../../HexagonLandXML/Point[@uniqueID = $pntRef]/Coordinates" />` pulls back those results from the above template where the `uniqueID` value matches the current template's `pntRef` value; so we only display the relevant rows for each pntRef.  NB: I've used a relative XPath in my select (`../../../HexagonLandXML/Point[@uniqueID = $pntRef]/Coordinates`; but could equally have used an absolute one (`/LandXML/HexagonLandXML/Point[@uniqueID = $pntRef]/Coordinates`).  The relative one works from the current template's match's context whilst the absolute one works from the source document's root element.  The latter is probably simpler to understand; but the former may be useful if there were any relation inferred from the XML's structure (though I don't think that's the case here).
- We repeat the above trick of using `apply-templates` to filter another template's matches when finding those TargetPoints which are related to the other template's stations.
- For the template which creates an entry per station we don't need to filter on the values; we simply extract all matches as they occur.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `<xsl:for-each select=".">`, you can remove that as inside a template there is only one context node anyway.

Then I think you should move the `<xsl:variable name="PointH" select="key('keyH', $Survey1L/@id)"/>` inside of the second `for-each`, but as `<xsl:variable name="PointH" select="key('keyH', TargetPoint/@pntRef)"/>`.

If you still have problems then consider to edit your XML and XSLT samples to be minimal but complete and consistent, currently your XML sample doesn't show any namespaces but your XSLT assumes at least two.